# how can we represent the following projection

Tags: functions

how can we express the following correctly.

$$f:E\to F  $$
$$E \subseteq C_1 \times C_2 \times C_3 \times C_4 $$

$$f|_A:A\to F$$
$$A \subseteq C_1 \times C_4 $$ 
here, I misused the notation of mathematical restriction. 
I am looking for some notation like $f|_A$

Comment: You've already got the right notation.

Comment: @GNUSupporter 8964民主女神 地下教會  in restriction A is a subset of E, but here it is not

Comment: My bad !  I'm writing an answer.

Comment: I'm leaving an answer as comments: projection can be written by Greek letters rho or pi, like $\pi_A^E$ which stands for the projection fron E to A.